# Kepler maps do not work when importing two geometry columns

Tags: python, jupyter, geopandas, kepler.gl

I can extend this question to show a working example but I think it's a bug, not a coding error.

I've got two separate sources of data that are joined using `sjoin`. This returns points from `df1` that are within a polygon outlined in `df2`.

I want to import the merged dataset using Kepler and display both the points **and** the polygon.

If I don't differentiate the geometry columns, the polygon coordinates get removed after the merge. On the other hand, if I rename the geometry column from df2 before the merge, it returns a type error.

For reference, I've plotted the polygon from df2 using Kepler *(without df1)* and it works fine.

Option 1 (removes polygon coordinates):

```
df1 = gpd.read_file('data1.shp')
df2 = gpd.read_file('data2.shp')

df1 = df1(epsg = 4326)
df2 = df1(epsg = 4326)

merge = gpd.sjoin(df1, df2, predicate = 'within', how = 'inner')

map1 = KeplerGl(height = 600)
map1.add_data(merge)
map1
```

Output: geometry column from df2 is lost. So cannot plot the polygon

Option 2 (TypeError):

```
df1 = gpd.read_file('data1.shp')
df2 = gpd.read_file('data2.shp')

df1 = df1(epsg = 4326)
df2 = df1(epsg = 4326)

df2['geomsaved'] = df2.geometry


merge = gpd.sjoin(df1, df2, predicate = 'within', how = 'inner')

map1 = KeplerGl(height = 600)
map1.add_data(merge)
map1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I'm finding **kepplergl** a painful library to work with...
- your error is expected and is not a bug.  Specifically **geopandas** only supports one *geometry* column
- what does this mean?  **kepplergl** will be using `__geo_interface__` to generate *geojson* from the **GeoDataFrame** that is then serialised to a string to pass to **JavaScript** code of **kepplergl**.  This fails as the second column is a **Series** of complex objects that is not converted to *geojson*.  This I have replicated below, same error in a simple MWE
- how to manage this?

  1. create two layers in **kepplergl** one is polygons other is points
  2. concatenate geometries to long **GeoDataFrame** and create one layer

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).sample(10)
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# does not fail
json.dumps(cities.sjoin(world).__geo_interface__)
# fails: TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable
json.dumps(cities.sjoin(world.assign(poly=lambda d: d["geometry"])).__geo_interface__)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error for both calls? `TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable`

Comment: so you are saying `json.dumps(cities.sjoin(world).__geo_interface__)` this fails? make sure you comment next line - if you are not clear which line the exception is coming from

Comment: Sorry, I just restarted the kernel and it worked. Thankyou